# Question about using formula to compute PCA transform in Python

Tags: python, pca, scikit-learn

I try to understand how the Python function `sklearn.decomposition.PCA` working. I read the documentation of the code package in Github about [transform function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13a/sklearn/decomposition/_base.py#L97). And I found the formula to compute the matrix it returns when you fit the original matrix(say A).

However, I found that when I use a different matrix(say B), and you apply the same formula for the coefficient you obtained from fitting matrix A. It does not work anymore.

I am super curious why this happened and hope someone can point me to the correct solution.

To prove that, I will present the code I run below.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
A=np.array([[1,1,2],[3,4,2],[5,5,3]])
pca_model=PCA(2)
pca_model.fit_transform(A)
```

The result is:

```
array([[ 3.0818756 , -0.23999655],
       [-0.42078046,  0.61522301],
       [-2.66109514, -0.37522647]])
```

I can recover this result by

```
np.dot((A-np.mean(A,axis=0)),np.transpose(pca_model.components_))
```

where I got:

```
array([[ 3.0818756 , -0.23999655],
       [-0.42078046,  0.61522301],
       [-2.66109514, -0.37522647]])
```

However, if I try with a different matrix B and use the components computed from A:

```
B=np.array([[1,5,7],[2,4,6]])
pca_model.transform(B)
```

I got

```
array([[-0.55447918, -1.10164678],
       [-0.37055733, -1.51766277]])
```

When I did

```
np.dot((B-np.mean(B,axis=0)),np.transpose(pca_model.components_))
```

I got

```
array([[-0.09196093,  0.208008  ],
       [ 0.09196093, -0.208008  ]])
```

Why did this happen?

Comment: why 'try different matrix B and use the components computed from A'? what does it mean?

Comment: Hi Haitao, I was doing PCA reduction dimensionality, which the method I use is to fit one matrix A (say training matrix), pca_model.fit_transform(A), and use the same components apply to matrix B (say testing matrix) without fitting, pca_model.transform(B).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! I should use

```
np.dot((B-np.mean(A,axis=0)),np.transpose(pca_model.components_))
```

Instead of taking the mean of matrix B. Now I obtain

```
array([[-0.55447918, -1.10164678],
      [-0.37055733, -1.51766277]])
```

which is only exactly the same as pca_model.transform(B).